# Is there a way to get only the numeric elements of a string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to make it easier for the clients to search for stuff like phone/mobile/fax numbers. For that to happen I want to strip both the search value and the relevant columns in my database of any non-numeric characters before comparing them. I'm using [these functions](http://venerableagents.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/mysql-numeric-functions/) to get only the numeric elements of the strings in mysql but they slow my queries down to a crawl when I use them.

Is there any way to do it without blowing my run times sky high?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your query times are exploding is because any use of such functions disables you from using any index. Since you are not searching directly on a field, but on the output of a function, there is no way mySQL can use an index to execute the query.

This is in addition to the fact that you have to compute the function output for each record.

Comment: Yeah I figured out as much, but I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately mySQL does not have function based indexes, otherwise that would be the way to go. The only way I can think of if you want to do it with only mySQL is to store a second column with the transformed output, index it, and search on that column

Answer (score 2):

The best way around these runtimes, if you have access and permission to do so, is to add a new column with the content you're filtering. Add a WRITE trigger to fill the column with the stripped values, run a script that updates the field once for all records. Add an index and include the new column. Then, in your application, use the new column for searches for a number value of a telephone. Downsides are table schema alterations and added code for the business logic and/or data abstraction layer.

Comment: Hm, if that's the only way then we'll probably skip this quality of life update for our customers, because adding that would take a lot of time for not very much benefit.

Comment: Well in our case it is quite much as we have about a million ways to add this kind of data, not to mention customizable fields that can also be defined as telephone numbers and stuff like that. Anyway, thanks for the help 0xCAFEBABE and have a +1

Comment: If I may, another tip. Requirements like this come around often, something neat and shiny to sell your applications, but it would take alot of time to implement it the right way. One way to do it and still feel ok is to implement a mechanism that can support this requirement until the next update. Make a generic table that is well-indexed, where you can insert dynamic features under certain keywords like "literal phone #" with the value then stripped. You can implement a function for the current version to look in the added table, then change the functionality for the next version to use a

Comment: real table (and a real column). This almost always requires lazy loading on the program side (i.e. only load if the UI asks for the value).

Comment: Well this is already a big update with refined search and filtering options for each and every relevant column and this numbers issue is more of an inhouse request. After talking to the project manager we decided it's really not useful since clients usually only search for 3-4 letters of a phone number and figure it out from there. It would be really awkward to search for part of the prefix/area code (you won't search for 555-1 to find 555-123 4567, you search for 4567). But anyway thanks for the tip, useful for a beginner like me, only been in the business for about 8 months.

Comment: Then let me welcome you to the club. Here's your complimentary rubber duck and googles (you know what they do).